# How to make django class based view truly threaded?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, thread-safety

Here is my class based django view which just loops over for 10000x5000 times and returns the time take for the ***for loop***:

```
class trying(View):
    def get(self, request):
        tic = dt.now()
        for i in range(10000):
            for j in range(5000):
                k = i+j
        data = str((dt.now() - tic).total_seconds())

        return HttpResponse(str(data))
```

So the time taken for the view to respond for a single request is around ***2.5 seconds***

When I made mutliple requests serially with 'n' second interval each response was also around ***2.5 seconds***

But when I made 4 simultaneous requests (I launched the requests at the exact same instance/time based on the system time) the time taken for the view to respond has increased to 20 seconds.
***Each view took 20 seconds*** to respond.

I made the respective changes in my apache configuration also to make use of the worker thread.

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess www.mysite.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
 WSGIProcessGroup www.mysite.com
```

But still the result was the same. 
From my basic research Django's views are thread safe.

What could be the reason for this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Why would you expect threading to help here? This code is clearly CPU bound, and in Python threading rarely helps in cases like that.

Comment: So let's say i'm serving just html/css files in that view , then there wouldn't be any difference in the response time ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, would multiprocessing help in such a case?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The problem with multiprocessing is that the actual use case has a significantly large memory requirement. So if we had to load all that memory in each process we would run into other problems. The goal was to use threads that could read from the same chunk of memory that is loaded just once at initialization.

Comment: Well, as I say, unfortunately threading won't help except when you're IO-bound.